# Why does my screen routing logic not work?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I want to make page transitions correctly with the ionic4 application migrated from ionic3.

I'd like to move settings page, but It doesn't work.

As the structure of page transition,
tabs are at the top, home is under that,
It is designed to transition from the home to the setting screen.
(Tabs⇒home⇒settings)

`this.router.navigateByUrl ('tabs / home / settings')`
, But the screen does not change even if the target button is clicked.
(There are other screens that can be transitioned correctly, but I can not tell the difference by comparing them.)

Please check out the code below.

home.page.hmtl

```
<ion-buttons class="settings-button" slot="primary">
 <ion-button icon-only (click)="selectFavorites()">
  <ion-icon name="ios-settings"></ion-icon>
 </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

home.page.ts

```
selectFavorites() {
 this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/home/settings');
}
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: '../home/fav-settings/fav-settings.module#FavSettingsPageModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule {}
```

settings.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    FavSettingsPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [FavSettingsPage]
})
export class FavSettingsPageModule {}
```

settings-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FavSettingsPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FavSettingsPageRoutingModule {}
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: TabsPage,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: () =>
            import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }
  ]
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LinkyModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot({mode:'ios', backButtonText: '', swipeBackEnabled: true}),
        AppRoutingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        Calendar,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        InAppBrowser,
        Geolocation,
        Network,
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

We apologize for any inconvenience, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try
`loadChildren: () => import('../home/fav-settings/fav-settings.module#').then(m => m.FavSettingsPageModule)`
in your **home-routing.module.ts**, make sure the module has been imported correctly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you your reply. I have tried `loadChildren: () => import('./fav-settings/fav-settings.module').then(m => m.FavSettingsPageModule)`. But nothing changed.
I'm really in trouble.

Comment: Hi there, if your trouble is from home page navigation to other page, you probably need to look into your fav-settings.module.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too long to understand for me, sorry if I'm not able to understand it correctly. Let me try to answer it in very simple way.

When we create new Ionic project we can see Home and List are by default two pages which are created.

So, `app-routing-module.ts` will look like below. I've moved both to new `pages` folder out of `app` folder, so accordingly you can see path in import.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('../pages/home/home.module').then(m=> m.HomePageModule) },
      { path: 'list', loadChildren: () => import('../pages/list/list.module').then(m=> m.ListPageModule) }}
    ];
```

Now, If by default if I want to route to specific page then my code will look like below.

```
    export class HomePage {
      constructor(private router: Router) { // on load of HomePage it will redirect to List Page
        this.router.navigateByUrl('list');
      }
    }
```

where `list` in `navigateByUrl` is name of `path` property of `Routes` array from `app-routing-module.ts`.

we don't need to pass fully qualifier route name like we do it in import in same Route array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can implement:

home.page.ts

```
selectFavorites() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('settings');
}
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: HomePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
      path: 'login',
      loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
    },
    {
      path: 'tabs',
      loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
    },
    {
       path: 'settings',
       loadChildren: () =>
          import('./home/fav-settings/fav-settings.module').then(
          m => m.FavSettingsPageModule
       )
    }
 ];

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
   ],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```